# Angular 5 - Sending POST request with HTML contents to OneNote API

Tags: angular, typescript, microsoft-graph-api, onenote

I have trouble making the POST request to Microsoft Graph OneNote API for creating new page.

According to [the docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/section_post_pages), I would need to create a boundary to send HTML contents of the page. But I can't figure out how to do it in Angular 5.

This is my current code:

```
const data = new HttpParams();
data.append('Content-Disposition', 'form-data; name="Presentation"');
data.append('Content-Type', 'text/html');
data.append('text', page.content);

const headers = {
  'Content-type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=MyPartBoundary198374`,
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.toString(),
};
return this.http.post(url + 'sections/' + sectionId.toString() + '/pages',
  data, {headers: headers});
```

How would I create this request? I am sure this is wrong, probably in appending page content, but no idea how to do it correctly with HttpClient module. All I am getting is error:

```
message:"Page create requests require the content to be multipart, with a presentation part.", 
statusText:"Unsupported Media Type"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your page.content just HTML? Because if so, "The body can contain HTML placed directly in the request body" instead of having to send it as a multipart request

Comment: @user184994 yes, it is, just pure HTML like: page.content = `<html>.. </html>`;

Comment: Then there is no need to send the "'Content-type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=MyPartBoundary198374`" header, you can just send the HTML

Comment: @user184994 even if I remove it, I am still getting the same error. I think the API actually requires this.

Comment: Nope, check the API documentation. It says "The body can contain HTML placed directly in the request body, or it can contain a multipart message format as shown in the example. If you're sending binary data, then you must send a multipart request." Seeing as you're not sending binary data, there is no need for you to send a multipart request

Comment: Instead of sending HttpParams (i.e. data), you should just be able to send the string,

Comment: @user184994 it's working! god, thank you so much, I'm an idiot.